# Unit test noncopyable object

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a noncopyable monster base class, I also have a IView class.
I have a hobgoblin class that inherits from both monster an IView ,
I have a controller that takes a pointer to IView as a parameter.
Basically I want to check if hobgoblin exploded.

I'm using gmock / gtest

I keep getting

```
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(h, Explode())...
         Expected: to be called at least once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

when i use the mock object. What am i missing?

**Monster Base**

```
#ifndef MONSTER_H
#define MONSTER_H

#include <string>

// interface for all monsters
class monster {
public:
    virtual ~monster();

    // forbid copying
    monster(monster const &) = delete;
    monster & operator=(monster const &) = delete;

    void receive_damage(double damage);
    void interact_with_chainsaw();
    std::string name() const;

protected:
    // allow construction for child classes only
    monster();

private:
    virtual void do_receive_damage(double damage) = 0;
    virtual void do_interact_with_chainsaw() = 0;
    virtual std::string do_name() const = 0;
};

#endif // MONSTER_H
```

**IView**

```
#ifndef IVIEW_H
#define IVIEW_H

class IView
{
public:
    virtual void Explode() = 0;
    virtual ~IView(){}
};
#endif // IVIEW_H
```

**Hobgoblin**

```
#ifndef HOBGOBLIN_H
#define HOBGOBLIN_H

#include "monster.h"
#include "iview.h"

class hobgoblin : public monster, public IView
{
public:
    hobgoblin();
    void Explode();
    virtual ~hobgoblin();

private:
    void do_receive_damage(double damage) final;
    void do_interact_with_chainsaw() final;
    std::string do_name() const final;

    double health_;
};

#endif // HOBGOBLIN_H

#include "hobgoblin.h"
#include <QDebug>

hobgoblin::hobgoblin() :
    health_(100.0)
{
}

hobgoblin::~hobgoblin()
{
}

void hobgoblin::Explode()
{
    health_ = 0;
    qDebug() << "Health is 0";
}

void hobgoblin::do_receive_damage(double damage)
{
    health_ -= damage;
}

void hobgoblin::do_interact_with_chainsaw()
{
    // imagine horrible, gory things here such as
    // having to deal with a singleton
}

std::string hobgoblin::do_name() const
{
    static std::string const name("Furry hobgoblin of nitwittery +5");
    return name;
}
```

**Controller**

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include "iview.h"

class Controller
{
public:
    Controller(IView *view);

    void Explode();

    ~Controller();

private:
    IView *m_View;
};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H

#include "controller.h"
#include <QDebug>

Controller::Controller(IView *view):
    m_View(view)
{

}

void Controller::Explode()
{
    m_View->Explode();
}

Controller::~Controller()
{

}
```

**Unit Test**

```
   class mockmonster : public IView
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(Explode,void());

    virtual ~mockmonster(){}
};

TEST(MockMonster,Explode)
{
    // this is not calling explode as expected.
    mockmonster h;
    Controller c(&h);
    c.Explode();

}

TEST(HobGoblin,Explode) 
{
    // this calls explode fine
    hobgoblin h;
    Controller c(&h);
    c.Explode();
}
```

Comment: There's nothing testing that the member function gets called in your example code. Maybe best to post a [mcve].

Comment: Here is simplified example of what i want to do. https://pastebin.com/JgDG4ab5 I get compiler errors now if want to use noncopyable object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, shouldn't your `Explode` function be virtual?

By the looks of it, your `mockmonster` is shadowing `IView`'s function. Since `Controller` is taking a pointer to `IView`, and `Explode` is non-virtual, it will invoke `IView`'s version.

---

As a side-note, I doubt if either of your classes being non-copyable matters here. When using gmock, non-copyable classes are problematic when setting up expectations/assertions (i.e. you expect a function to be called with a specific object - this object would have to be copied internally by gmock, and that might fail).

Comment: When using gmock, non-copyable classes are problematic when setting up expectations/assertions (i.e. you expect a function to be called with a specific object - this object would have to be copied internally by gmock, and that might fail). that is what I'm having difficulty with. I need to work with a noncopyable class and make sure that the functions inside are running in order. I am having difficulty finding a simple working example.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez So if you make the type copyable it works?

Comment: @juanchopanza yes.